# Data Mapper, Model, Repository

Tags: php, model-view-controller, datamapper

## SOLUTION

Please make sure to read the whole topic, and at the end read the solution, which i'll try to explain. I've kind of created my own `ORM (Object Related Mapping)` which solves the problem of models with joined table. Let's take the example that I've provided down below.

#### Model (Cart)

```
<?php

namespace Eshop\Model;

class CartModel
{
    private int   $quantity;
    private int   $customer_id;
    private array $products; //You are saving here your Product Model 


    /**
     * @param ProductModel[]
     * @return array
    */
    public function getProducts(): array
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    /**
     * @param ProductModel[] $products
     */
    public function setProducts(array $products): void
    {
        $this->products = $products;
    }

    /**
     * @param ProductModel $productsModel
     */
    public function setProduct(ProductModel $productsModel): void
    {
        $this->products[] = $productsModel;
    }
```

#### Repository

```
    public function getCartItems(int $customerId): array|bool
    {
        $tableName = $this->setTableName(); // Cart Table
        $statement = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT cart.quantity, cart.customer_id, product.productid, product.name, product.imagepath, product.price FROM `$tableName` as cart LEFT JOIN product as product ON product.productid = cart.product_id WHERE cart.customer_id=:customerId AND cart.ordered=0;");
        $statement->execute(['customerId' => $customerId]);
        $rows = $statement->fetchAll();
        $cartModel= new CartModel(); 
        foreach($rows as $row){
          $productModel = new ProductModel() 
          $productModel->setName($row['name])
          $productModel->setPrice($row['price])
          $cartModel->setProduct($productModel) 
         }
        return $cartModel
    }
```

Now we have a Product Model stored inside array.

### View

Store the repository inside controller (I used `$userCart` variable)

```
<?php 

  foreach($userCart->getProducts() as $userCart){
     //Now you are able to use getters and setters of ProductModel 
     echo $userCart->getName();
     echo $userCart->getPrice();
}

?>
```

---

## Original Post

I am using MVC Pattern, and so far I have Repository (where all SQL statements happens, and PDO stuff), I have Controller which renders the repository to the View, and I have Model with private properties, and getters / setters, where the Objects are fetched.

So far, I used `FETCH_CLASS` and stored everything inside one **Model**, and then on View I called the getter methods to display it. But I need to use now some kind of Data Mapper, which is going to allow me to store information to model manually (because I have Joins in statements, and want to store for example Cart Data that comes from Cart Table to Cart Model, and Product Data that comes from Product Table to Product Model.

#### Repository

Like I said, I've used `FETCH_CLASS` but in this case I need another solution

```
    public function getCartItems(int $customerId): array|bool
    {
        $tableName = $this->setTableName(); // Cart Table
        $statement = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT cart.quantity, cart.customer_id, product.productid, product.name, product.imagepath, product.price FROM `$tableName` as cart LEFT JOIN product as product ON product.productid = cart.product_id WHERE cart.customer_id=:customerId AND cart.ordered=0;");
        $statement->execute(['customerId' => $customerId]);
        return $statement->fetchAll();
    }
```

#### Model (Cart)

```
<?php

namespace Eshop\Model;

class CartModel
{
    private int   $quantity;
    private int   $customer_id;
    private array $products;


    /**
     * @param ProductModel[]
     * @return array
    */
    public function getProducts(): array
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    /**
     * @param ProductModel[] $products
     */
    public function setProducts(array $products): void
    {
        $this->products = $products;
    }

    /**
     * @param ProductModel $productsModel
     */
    public function setProduct(ProductModel $productsModel): void
    {
        $this->products[] = $productsModel;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getQuantity(): int
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $quantity
     */
    public function setQuantity(int $quantity): void
    {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCustomerId(): int
    {
        return $this->customer_id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $customer_id
     */
    public function setCustomerId(int $customer_id): void
    {
        $this->customer_id = $customer_id;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getOrdered(): int
    {
        return $this->ordered;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $ordered
     */
    public function setOrdered(int $ordered): void
    {
        $this->ordered = $ordered;
    }
}
```

#### Model (Product)

```
<?php

namespace Eshop\Model;

/** Getters and Setters for Model */
class ProductModel
{
    /** Product Table */
    private int    $productid;
    private string $name;
    private string $description;
    private float  $price;
    private string $imagepath;



    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductid(): int
    {
        return $this->productid;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $productid
     */
    public function setProductid(int $productid): void
    {
        $this->productid = $productid;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName(string $name): void
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription(): string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $description
     */
    public function setDescription(string $description): void
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getPrice(): float
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * @param float $price
     */
    public function setPrice(float $price): void
    {
        $this->price = $price;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImagepath(): string
    {
        return $this->imagepath;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $imagepath
     */
    public function setImagepath(string $imagepath): void
    {
        $this->imagepath = $imagepath;
    }
    
}
```

#### Cart Controller

```
/**
     * Cart System
     */
    public function cart(): void
    {
        //The Message and Total Price are false until...
        $messages = false;
        $totalPrice = false;

        //Get product from customer's cart
        $customerCartItems = $this->cartService->getCartForCustomer();


        //If there is nothing in cart, print out the message
        if ($customerCartItems === false) {
            $messages = $this->cartService->getMessages();
        } else {
            // Else Get Total Price in cart
            $totalPrice = $this->cartService->getTotalPrice();
        }

        //Render to view
        $this->render('cart', ['cartUser' => $customerCartItems, 'messages' => $messages, 'totalPrice' => $totalPrice]);
    }
```

#### View

`FETCH_CLASS` was used on ProductModel, so I've easily return the values with getters. But in this case, I can't.

```
    <?php foreach ($cartUser as $cartItem) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img class="cart-images" src="<?php echo $cartItem->getImagepath(); ?>">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p><?php echo $cartItem->getName(); ?></p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
```

Any Idea?

Comment: You say: _"...because I have Joins in statements, and want to store for example Cart Data [...] to Cart Model, and Product Data [...] to Product Model."_. For which purpose do you need the resulting data coming from that JOIN statements? If you need the data only to display it to the users of your application - which I expect, then you don't need to distribute it (e.g. save it) to any model objects. Instead you should just prepare it for display and display it.

Comment: But, if you need the resulting data coming from that JOIN statements to fill **more than one** model object at a time, **of different types**, then your application algorithms are wrong and you need to rethink them.

Comment: So, in principle, you should fill one model object at a time, even if data comes from multiple tables. In such a way, that a class method of yours, responsible with querying the database and conversion of the table data to model object properties, should be in position to return either only one model object, or an array of model objects **of the same type**.

Comment: For example, in your `Repository` you could have a method `fetchProductById` which could use a method `convertDataArrayComingFromTablesToProductModel` in order to return a `ProductModel` object. And you could also have a method `fetchAllProducts` which could use a method `convertListOfDataArraysComingFromTablesToListOfProductModels` in order to return a list of `ProductModel` objects.

Comment: _Note_: Your `Repository` is actually a [data mapper](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html). A [repository](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) should be a class additional to a data mapper class and should be seen and used purely as a **collection of objects** of the same type.

Comment: I would recommend you to see [this video](https://vimeo.com/107963074). Minute _20:10_ is especially relevant for you.

Comment: @dakis that is **not** a datamapper, but a table data gateway.